# How can i suggest intents to user in wit.ai?

Tags: wit.ai

I want to create a feedback mechanism where if wit.ai fails to understand some command it can suggest a list of intents to be chosen by user and using this I can update the synonym under that entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this url to get all your intents:

```
curl -XGET 'https://api.wit.ai/entities/intent?v=20170101'   -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"
{
 "builtin" : false,
 "doc" : "User-defined entity",
 "exotic" : false,
 "id" : "58731dcc-3180-43c9-46fd-8881447d9f0c",
 "lang" : "en",
 "lookups" : [ "trait" ],
 "name" : "intent",
 "values" : [ {
   "value" : "demo-free",
   "expressions" : [ "@Cortex, is demo free?", "Is demo free?" ]
 }, {
   "value" : "demo-info",
   "expressions" : [ "@Cortex, who is using demo?", "@Cortex, Who's using demo?", "Who's using it?", "Who's using demo?" ]
 }, {
   "value" : "mongo-status",
   "expressions" : [ "@Cortex, is mongo2 ok?", "@Cortex, how is mongo1?", "@Cortex, is mongo1 ok?", "@Cortex, is mongo ok>", "is mongo-1 ok?", "@Cortex, is mongodb ok?", "@Cortex, is mongo ok?", "how are the mongo servers?", "how are the mongod servers?", "is mongo ok", "is mongodb ok?", "Mongo status", "Check mongo status" ]
 }, {
   "value" : "cortex-help",
   "expressions" : [ "what can you do for me?", "help me", "help", "how can you help me?", "What can you do?" ]
 }, {
   "value" : "mongo-logs",
   "expressions" : [ "@Cortex, can I see all the db logs?", "@Cortex, can I see all db logs?", "@Cortex, can I see the mongo logs?", "can I see the mongo logs?", "can I see the mongod logs?", "let me see the mongo logs", "can I see the mongodb logs?", "show me mongo logs", "show me the mongo logs" ]
 } ]
```

You can use this to pick one (or more) example(s) of each intent and show those to your users.

Comment: if you use old apps (without stories), you can use the doc field to put the question related to your intent and then use this call to retrieve: https://wit.ai/docs/http/20160526#get--intents-(deprecated)-link